# Color font glyphs

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows

I'm needing a discussion on using a custom font with glyph of different but specific colors.

In a related question I asked if I could print TrueType 3, color glyphs, using vb.net programing.

I was told that Windows did not support color glyphs.

If this is indeed true (I believe it is), is there any technology which can print a font with individually colored glyphs. It's not enough to render each glyph individually changing its fill color. The font would have individually different colored "clear space" around and in the glyph.

This font is not an exersise in futility but a font for the visually handicapped.

To reiterate the question, is there any way to render a font with individually colored glyphs. (book, paper, web suggestions would also be appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1 supports colored fonts. See *[Color Emoji in Windows 8.1—The Future of Color Fonts?](http://opentype.info/blog/2013/07/03/color-emoji-in-windows-8-1-the-future-of-color-fonts/)*